# splitting a list into multiple lists

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following list:

```
List("Chapter 1", "2", "This is a sentence", "English")
```

I would like to split it as follows:

```
List("Chapter 1", "2", "This", "English")
List("Chapter 1", "2", "is", "English")
List("Chapter 1", "2", "a", "English")
List("Chapter 1", "2", "sentence", "English")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val list = List("Chapter 1", "2", "This is a sentence", "English")
list(2).split(" ").map(x => list.patch(2, List(x), 1))
```

Comment: Be careful since `List#apply`, i.e. `list(2) === list#apply(2)`, is not a total function. `scala> List().apply(2) --> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

Comment: Kevin, can you please elaborate?